# How to increase the number of vertices?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need a parametric form for a `matplotlib.path.Path`. So I used the `.vertices` attribute, and it works fine except that the number of points given is too low for the use I want. Here is a code to illustrate :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpat

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(-6, 6), ylim=(-6, 6))


# generate a circular path
circle = mpat.Arc((0, 0), 10, 10, theta1=20, theta2=220, color='green')
path = circle.get_transform().transform_path(circle.get_path()).cleaned().vertices[:-3]  # get_path is not enough because of the transformation, so we apply to the path the same transformation as the circle has got from the identity circle
ax.add_patch(circle)

# plot path vertices
plt.scatter(x=path[:, 0], y=path[:, 1], color='red', s=2)

shape = len(path)

plt.show()
```

How to increase the number of points (red) to fetch better the path (green)? Or, how can I increase the `len` of `path`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you can just loop over many shorter arcs, e.g.,:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpat

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(-6, 6), ylim=(-6, 6))


# generate a circular path
dr = 30  # change this to control the number of points
path = np.empty((0, 2))

for i in range(20, 221, dr):
    circle = mpat.Arc((0, 0), 10, 10, theta1=i, theta2=(i + dr), color='green')
    tmppath = circle.get_transform().transform_path(circle.get_path()).cleaned().vertices[:-1]
    path = np.vstack((path, tmppath[:, 0:2]))

    ax.add_patch(circle)

# plot path vertices
plt.scatter(x=path[:, 0], y=path[:, 1], color='red', s=2)

plt.show()
```

**Update**

Another option is to hack the [`Arc`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html) class, so that during [initialisation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.2/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L1898-L2143), the [`Path.arc`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/dc0328fb9c1c8817b07a5121a106a06be3571433/lib/matplotlib/path.py#L926) takes in the `n` keyword. E.g.,

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Path, Arc

class NewArc(Arc):
    def __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle=0.0, theta1=0.0, theta2=360.0, n=30, **kwargs):
        """
        An Arc class with the n keyword argument
        """
    
        fill = kwargs.setdefault('fill', False)
        if fill:
            raise ValueError("Arc objects can not be filled")

        super().__init__(xy, width, height, angle=angle, **kwargs)

        self.theta1 = theta1
        self.theta2 = theta2
        (self._theta1, self._theta2, self._stretched_width,
         self._stretched_height) = self._theta_stretch()

        # add in the n keyword here
        self._path = Path.arc(self._theta1, self._theta2, n=n)
```

The original code (without the for loop) can then be used and the number of points increased, e.g.,

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(-6, 6), ylim=(-6, 6))

# generate a circular path using NewArc and the n keyword
circle = NewArc((0, 0), 10, 10, theta1=20, theta2=220, n=40, color='green')
path = circle.get_transform().transform_path(circle.get_path()).cleaned().vertices[:-3]
ax.add_patch(circle)

# plot path vertices
ax.scatter(x=path[:, 0], y=path[:, 1], color='red', s=2)

fig.show()
```

Comment: It works in this particular case, but if `theta1 = 0.5` and `theta2 = 0.7` , or if the path is "more random" this roundabout solution is not working... Can you think of anything more "general" ? I still haven't found anything

Comment: Another option would be to make an interpolation function from the `path`, using, e.g., [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) and then get the output from over an increased number of samples. However, unless you transform things correctly, the new points would not necessarily be linearly spaced along the arc.

Comment: I've worked out a better solution and added it to the answer

Comment: Wow, thanks, I did not think of that! Is there a reason why the matplotlib developers didn't add this `n` parameter in optional arg to `matplotlib.patches.Arc` when it's there for `matplotlib.Path.arc`?

Answer (score 0):

This annoyed me enough that I wrote a simple alternative implementation. It doesn't rely on `Arc` at all, and works fine:

```py
import typing
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.path import Path

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from matplotlib.transforms import Transform
    from matplotlib.typing import ColourType


def hires_arc(
    centre: tuple[float, float],
    radius: float,
    theta1: float,
    theta2: float,
    n: int = 10,
    colour: typing.Optional['ColourType'] = None,
    transform: typing.Optional['Transform'] = None,
    zorder: int | None = None,
) -> PathPatch:
    """
    matplotlib's Arc patch looks pretty bad; it has a low and non-configurable resolution. This does
    basically the same thing but with controllable resolution.

    :param centre: x, y pair, centre of circle
    :param radius: from centre
    :param theta1: start angle, radians
    :param theta2: end angle, radians
    :param n: number of vertices
    :param colour: passed to the patch
    :param transform: passed to the patch
    :param zorder: passed to the patch
    """
    codes = np.full(shape=n, fill_value=Path.LINETO, dtype=Path.code_type)
    codes[0] = Path.MOVETO

    angles = np.linspace(start=theta1, stop=theta2, num=n)
    vertices = centre + radius*np.stack((
        np.cos(angles), np.sin(angles),
    ), axis=1)

    return PathPatch(
        path=Path(vertices=vertices, codes=codes),
        edgecolor=colour, facecolor='none', zorder=zorder, transform=transform,
    )
```

Alternatively, transform a path with the built-in `Path.arc`:

```py
    scale = Affine2D().scale(radius).translate(
        tx=centre[0], ty=centre[1],
    )
    path = Path.arc(
        theta1=theta1, theta2=theta2, n=n,
    ).transformed(scale)
    return PathPatch(
        path=path, edgecolor=colour, facecolor='none', zorder=zorder, transform=transform,
    )
```